# No puedo agregar usuario usando Java EE y MySQL. No encuentro el error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, java-ee

Hola estoy tratando de insertar un usuario y no lo logro concretar. no encuentro error en el código, sin embargo no se logra.

**JSP DEL FORMULARIO:**

```
<form action="operador" method="post">

                <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" 
class="validate">

                <input id="apellido" type="text" name="apellido" class="validate">

                <input id="rut" type="text" name="rut" class="validate">


                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="validate">

                <input id="telefono" type="number" name="telefono" class="validate">

                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="validate">

                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="validate">

                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2" id="level" class="validate">

            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">GUARDAR

            </button>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="reset" name="action">BORRAR DATOS

            </button>
             <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">CANCELAR

            </button>


    </form>
```

**EL CONTROLADOR DEL USUARIO ES EL SIGUIENTE**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   //int idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUsuario"));
   //ES AUTOINCREMENTABLE EN LA BASE DE DATOS , NO SE NECESITA
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
    String rut = request.getParameter("rut");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    int telefono = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("telefono"));
    int level = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("level"));

    Usuario operador = new Usuario(0);
    //operador.setIdUsuario(idUsuario);
    // NO RECIBE PARAMETRO
    operador.setNombre(nombre);
    operador.setApellido(apellido);
    operador.setRut(rut);
    operador.setUsername(username);
    operador.setPassword(password);
    operador.setEmail(email);
    operador.setTelefono(telefono);
    operador.setLevel(level);

    System.out.println(operador);

    DbConnection conn = new DbConnection();
    OperadorDao operadorDao = new OperadorDao(conn);
    boolean status = operadorDao.insert(operador);

    //Preparamos un mensaje para el usuario

    String msg = "";
    if(status){
        msg = "El operador fue creado correctamente.";
    }else{
        msg = "Ocurrio un error. El operador no fue creado.";
    }

    conn.disconnect();
    RequestDispatcher rd;

    //Compartiomos la variable msg para poder accederla desde la vista con Expression Language
    request.setAttribute("message", msg);
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/mensaje.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

**CLASE DAO CON FUNCIÓN INSERT (INSERT EN BASE DE DATOS)**

```
    public class OperadorDao {

DbConnection conn;

public OperadorDao(DbConnection conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}

//Método para insertar registro de operadores
public boolean insert(Usuario operador){
    String sql = "insert into usuario (nombre,apellido,rut,email,username,password,telefono,level)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, operador.getNombre());
        ps.setString(2, operador.getApellido());
        ps.setString(3, operador.getRut());
        ps.setString(4, operador.getEmail());
        ps.setString(5, operador.getUsername());
        ps.setString(6, operador.getPassword());
        ps.setInt(7, operador.getTelefono());
        ps.setInt(8, operador.getLevel());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return false;
    }

}



}
```

**NOTAS :**

- El ID del usuario es autoincrementable
- El todos los valores son recibidos pero no son insertados

espero me puedan ayudar, quedo atento a sus respuestas. 
Saludos.

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro pero a simple vista parece que te falta un espacio delante de "values" en esta línea: String sql = "insert into usuario (nombre,apellido,rut,email,username,password,telefono,level)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: Dos tremendos errores que no te dejan ver que esta pasando: executeUpdate siempre regresa una respuesta para que sepas si se hizo o no la operación. Esa respuesta no la estas recibiendo(cachando). En el catch imprime ex.printStackTrace() para que puedas ver la traza de los errores que salen, si es que hay. Por eso no puedes determinar porque no lo hace, porque tienes serías fallas al recibir la información de BD. No se trata solo de decirle a la base de datos "haz esto", debes verificar que lo haya hecho y actuar en consecuencia, y si no pudo hacerlo también actuar en esa consecuencia.